# Is it possible to compile C source code into R so that the resulting R function is platform independent?

Tags: c, r, cross-platform

I want to write an R function that calls my C code and does not require me to re-compile the C code on every possible platform (into either binaries or SO/DLLs). Is such a thing possible?

Comment: No. Compiled languages, by definition, must be compiled on each platform they are run on.

Comment: Not false by definition.  It would be feasible for R to have a run-time compile of C source code that could work for whatever platform the user is using.  Or for R to have an install-c-package option that takes in the C source code and compiles into a pre-defined R function automatically, the compilation of which would depend on the platform R is running on.  It can certainly be done, it's just a question of whether anyone has written function into R to do it.

Comment: Sure, you can call `gcc` or `make` from within R using `system`.

Comment: Thanks - though what I want is an R function than non-technical people (specifically empirical ecologists who read my publications) will be happy to use, rather than ask them to compile the source code.  My current best options are either to create binaries for each platform (Win, Linux, Mac, 32bit, 64bit etc.) and then explain how to use system() to call them, or create object/DLL files for each platform.  It would be nice not to have to do this - but I'm not sure there is a possible way.

Comment: You could build it as a package. When you build a binary for the package, it will automatically generate binaries for each platform.

Comment: Thanks - that could be useful way to do it

Answer (score 2):

As per the excellent comments,  make your code into a `package` .  Better yet, submit the package to CRAN.  They'll take care of distributing binaries for Linux, OSX, and Windows.

Check out `utils::package.skeleton` for a handy tool to set up your package, and D/L (from CRAN) the manual `R-exts.pdf` for details on formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Use the inline package (with Rcpp):

```
# with  Rcpp plugin
if( require( Rcpp ) ) {
  fx <- cxxfunction( signature(x = "integer", y = "numeric" ) , ’
    return wrap( as<int>(x) * as<double>(y) ) ;
  ’, plugin = "Rcpp" )
fx( 2L, 5 )
```

Comment: I think this will only work if the end users have all the relevant compilation tools installed, which may not be true if they're non-technical?